# can i track the users location for every minute and how does it effect the battery life of the mobile

Tags: geolocation, battery

This question is regarding user location and battery management.
i am trying to develop an app which need to track the users location all the time, so is it possible and how severely does it effect the mobile's battery

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Cordova / Phonegap to build your app, check this out: https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation